# Lightweight tabulation written in Python

Tags: python, optimization

I wrote this module in python for some minor tabulation needs in my science projects. This was very helpful for testing, debugging and plotting various data. I often use dictionaries for storing such data, either as an array or as in a spreadsheet (column and row). This tiny script helps me to plot such data in a similar fashion. Since I find myself using it a lot, I thought of improving it in terms of performance and readability. Also, I do understand that there are several [third party libraries](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/tabulate) available for python to do the same with much more functionality, but I did it anyway for learning the language and ... well, and for fun. How could I refactor this code so that I could optimize it and possibly expand it in the future?

## Summary

- For dictionaries only
- Rows can be specified separately for excluding some data
- Automatic column spacing
- Automatic table breaking (terminal size)
- Specify headers and alignment

Dictionaries represent columns. Their keys marks the rows and their values contains the cell data. This produces the structure cell=column[row] which is very much similar to the A1 structure in spreadsheet programs.

I have added doc strings and comments to make this somewhat readable, but I would very much appreciate it if you could suggest an improvement. The `Table` class could be instantiated to specify rows and other features. User could then add columns using `AddColumn` method and that's pretty much it. Use `Show` to view the final table.

The `[[]]` in the code are used for containing info about each breaks in the table. `[[break1], [break2], [break3] ...]`. Each of these breaks contains columns that could fit inside the terminal window. `[[c1,c2,c3...c7], [c8,c9], [c10,c11...] ...]`.

```
from shutil import get_terminal_size as termsize


class Table(object):
    """Lightweight tabulation class for dictionary type containers.

    Dictionaries represents columns of the table, and their values the cells.
    Keys identifies the rows of the table.
    """

    def __init__(self, rows, header="",align="<"):
        """Initialize the table by setting rows.

        'rows' must be an iterable containing the keys for every column. Each
        cell in the table is represented as : cell = column[row].
        Header for the row can be specified through 'head'.
        """
        # Row info
        self.rows = rows
        self.rowlength = self.GetMaxLength(rows, [header]) + 2
        self.rowstyle = "".join(("{:", align, str(self.rowlength), "}"))
        self.rowhead = self.rowstyle.format(str(header))

        # Table info (list of lists)
        self.columns = [[]]
        self.styles = [[]]
        self.headers = [[]]

        self.linelength = self.rowlength
        self.linelimit = termsize().columns


    def GetMaxLength(self, *iterables, threshold=0):
        """Returns the length of the longest item among the iterables.

        'threshold', if specified, must be the cut-off value of length.
        """
        for item in iterables:
            length = max(len(str(i)) for i in item)
            if length > threshold:
                threshold = length
        return threshold


    def AddColumn(self, content, header="", align="<"):
        """Adds a column to the table.

        'content' must be a dictionary containing the column values.
        Header for the column can be specified using 'header' argument.
        """
        length = self.GetMaxLength(content.values(), [header]) + 2
        style = "".join(("{:", align, str(length), "}"))

        self.linelength += length
        if self.linelength > self.linelimit:
            # Breaks the table
            self.columns.append([content])
            self.styles.append([style])
            self.headers.append([style.format(str(header))])
            self.linelength = self.rowlength + length
        else:
            # Resumes without breaking the table
            self.columns[-1].append(content)
            self.styles[-1].append(style)
            self.headers[-1].append(style.format(str(header)))


    def Show(self):
        """Displays the table."""
        for cols, stls, heds in zip(self.columns, self.styles, self.headers):
            # Print headers
            print("\n\x1b[7;1m", self.rowhead, "".join(heds), "\x1b[0m", sep="")
            # Print cells
            for row in self.rows:
                line = [s.format(str(c[row])) for s, c in zip(stls,cols)]
                print("\x1b[1m", self.rowstyle.format(row), "\x1b[0m",
                      "".join(line), sep="")


def test():
    # Sample data
    from random import sample
    rows = sample(range(100,200), 10)
    data = {k:v for k,v in zip(rows, sample(Table.__doc__.split(),10))}

    # Tabulate them
    table = Table(rows, header="INDEX")
    for i in range(3):
        table.AddColumn(data, header="LEFT ALIGN")
    for i in range(3):
        table.AddColumn(data, header="CENTRE ALIGN", align="^")
    for i in range(3):
        table.AddColumn(data, header="RIGHT ALIGN", align=">")
    table.Show()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    test()
```

Answer (score 3):

I think you shouldn't use the word `threshold` as a `GetMaxLength` parameter. It implies to me that it's a maximum value, but it's instead treated as a minimum. You then say it's the "cut-off value of length" which is ambiguous to me again. I'd just call it `min` and then it's self explanatory.

```
def GetMaxLength(self, *iterables, min=0):
    """Returns the length of the longest item among the iterables.

    'min', if specified, is the minimum possible value of length.
    """
```

Also I think `draw` is a more appropriate name for printing the table. You could possibly even implement it as `__repr__` so that the table could be drawn with `repr(Table)`. Though in that case I'd implement a nice `__str__` method too in case people try to print it unwittingly in a sentence because `'{}'.format(Table)` would call `__repr__` if you didn't have a `__str__` method defined.

Your naming in general should match the style guide ([PEP0008](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)), which suggests that function names be all lowercase with underscores as separators, not CamelCase. So `get_max_length` would be more appropriate.